# How to calculate cost in for GCS rewrite operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-kms

I recently switched the key of a bucket from being managed by Google to being managed by the customer. However, the existing files in the bucket are still using the old key. To resolve this, I need to rewrite the files so that they can utilize the new key. Can you please assist me in calculating the cost of this migration?

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rewrite

Comment: Do the reverse. Show the calculation that you have made and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this documentation on [Google Cloud Storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), rewrite operation (`storage.objects.rewrite`) will fall under **Class A Operations**.

For buckets located in a single [region](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-r):

| Storage Class | Class A operations (per 1,000 operations) |
| --- | --- |
| Standard storage | $0.005 |
| Nearline storage and Durable Reduced Availability (DRA) storage | $0.01 |
| Coldline storage | $0.02 |
| Archive storage | $0.05 |

For buckets located in a [dual-region](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-dr) or [multi-region](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-mr):

| Storage Class | Class A operations (per 1,000 operations) |
| --- | --- |
| Standard storage | $0.01 |
| Nearline storage and Durable Reduced Availability (DRA) storage | $0.02 |
| Coldline storage | $0.04 |
| Archive storage | $0.10 |

Please be advised that these are all just estimates and pricing may change depending on the region, operations, and Google Cloud [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms)  and [Program Policies](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup), as well as Google's [Privacy Policy](http://www.google.com/privacypolicy.html).

You may also check [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) for estimates of operations for your project.

Finally, you may reach out to [Google Cloud Billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) to properly explain all the charges that may incur during the operations of your project.